# Show that a 3-uniform hypergraph on $n \geq 5$ points, in which each pair of points occurs in the same (positive) number of edges, is not 2-colorable.

Tags: solution-verification, coloring, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

Here a graph is called properly colored if all of its edges contain vertices of different colors.

I'm not sure that I understand the construction in the question correctly. It seems to me the property of the graph is equivalent to having all vertices occurring in the same number of edges. If the hyperedges are represented as triangles, then the graph is a collection of triangles and is also regular.

If so isn't the following a counter-example? Each vertex belongs to four triangles, and none of the triangles is monochromatic.

[image]

Comment: "It seems to me the property of the graph is equivalent to having all vertices occurring in the same number of edges." Well, it shouldn't, because the equivalence is false. Consider $\{1,2,3\},\{2,3,4\},\{4,5,6\},\{1,5,6\}$. Each of the numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6$ appears twice. However, the number of times the pair $\{1,2\}$ occurs once while the pair $\{1,4\}$ occurs zero times. Your confusion is understandable though; the discrepancy is that "pair of points" refers to the ordered pair of points rather than the two points separately, as you assumed.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've been occupied with other problems. I'm not sure I understand the clarification in the last sentence of your post. However, upon revising my "counter-example", I think it doesn't reflect what I meant to say. I was thinking along the line of "all pairs of points occurring in the same number of edges".

Comment: or, in the representation I have above, "all edges belong to the same number of triangles".